# Function to_bytes shows wrong output

Tags: python

Python3 function to_bytes shows wrong output

```
num = 9
num.to_bytes(4,'big')
```

Output

```
b'\x00\x00\x00\t'
```

Expected output

```
b'\x00\x00\x00\x09'
```

Comment: The tab character `\t` is ASCII character 9 - `\x09` or `0x09`

Comment: Check output of `ord("\t")`. If you what to print bytes in hex form, there's [`bytes.hex()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.hex), `b"\x00\x00\x00\t".hex(" ")`

Comment: .hex() works OK, thanks

Comment: It's not *incorrect* in the first place. `bytes.__repr__` uses printable ASCII characters where possible, falling back to `\xXX` the necessary. If you want a specific different string, you'll have to write your own function.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, [`int.to_bytes()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.to_bytes) returns an ASCII representation implementation of which you can see in [CPython's `bytesobject.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/145bf269df3530176f6ebeab1324890ef7070bf8/Objects/bytesobject.c#L1292) specifically [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/145bf269df3530176f6ebeab1324890ef7070bf8/Objects/bytesobject.c#L1341).

You can instead use a [`bytearray`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#bytearray) if you want the numeric only or call [`ord()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord):

```py
bytearray((9).to_bytes(4, byteorder="big"))[3]
9
```

Or use [`hex()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hex) / [`bytes.hex()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.hex):

```py
>>> [hex(item) for item in (9).to_bytes(4, byteorder="big")]
['0x0', '0x0', '0x0', '0x9']
```

```py
>>> (9).to_bytes(4, byteorder="big").hex()
'00000009'
>>> (9).to_bytes(4, byteorder="big").hex(" ")
'00 00 00 09'
```

Comment: Your last list comprehension returns list of `0x..` strings which is kinda useless. To show bytes in form of hex string, there's `bytes.hex()`.